# Pulling options from select menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

This may be quite rudimentary, but I can't seem to get this. I have a few select menu's set up on a Jquery mobile page, and need to pull the values currently selected for use in a query string to pass to a search page. I know `$("#select-choice-1").val()` could pull it, but I want to hold and pass it. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: I'm just planning to pass it along to another function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var value = $("#select-choice-1").val(); // store the value within a variable

useValue(value); // call your function with arguments of value

function useValue(val) {
  // use that value through val
  alert(val);
}
```

OR, within in `change` event handler

```
$("#select-choice-1").change(function() {
  var value = this.value;
  // use value what ever you need
  useValue(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` to create the query string: http://jsfiddle.net/imsky/CQ7Cv/

```
$("select").map(function() {
        return $(this).attr("name") + "=" + $(this).val()
}).toArray().join("&")
```